# Move GameObject certain distance when I click

Tags: javascript, c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a game in Unity and I want to move an object a certain distance when I click a button and then stop until I click it again. I have tried with the Lerp function but I can't make the desired effect correctly

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.SmoothDamp.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanted to do this instantly then that's easy enough, you simply detect for mouse input and then move the object in whatever direction you want it to. Here's some sample c# code to do just that (In the update function).

```
if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
{
    transform.Translate(Vector3ToMove);
}
```

The variable Vector3ToMove would be a Vector3 storing the vector that you want it to move relative to it's current position. This is functional however it's not smooth and isn't particularly pleasing to look at. In order to achieve smooth movement you need to use a Lerp function, this lerp function needs to be called for multiple frames for it to reach the position, that may have been where you went wrong before. Here's some sample code to achieve the smooth effect using [Vector3.Lerp](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html)

```
Vector3 TargetPosition;
float speed = 1f;

void Start()
{
    TargetPosition = transform.position;
}    

void Update()
{
    if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        TargetPosition += Vector3ToMove;
    }

    transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, TargetPosition, speed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Vector3ToMove just like the previous example is the vector increment that you want to apply to the objects position. You may want to tweak the speed variable in the example provided there to get a nice smooth speed, you can also try using [Vector3.SmoothDamp](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.SmoothDamp.html) to get a slightly different smoothing effect.

Comment: Thanks so much! that's exactly what I needed :)

Comment: But what if I don't want to do the movement from the Mouse or keyboard but a Canvas Button?

Comment: You would use the Unity event system to do so, you would create a function which has the code I put in the Input if statement and then using the Unity UI event system you would call the function using the pressed event.

https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui/ui-events-and-event-triggers